# How to calculate the log return of portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-management, quant-trading-strategies, portfolio, log-returns, asset-returns

Suppose that we have five trades each day with these returns ($R_{day,trade}$) and we have 300 days in total:

$R_{1,1}$, $R_{1,2}$, $R_{1,3}$, $R_{1,4}$, $R_{1,5}$

$R_{2,1}$, $R_{2,2}$, $R_{2,3}$, $R_{2,4}$, $R_{2,5}$

For each day, we calculate the return of that day by weighting these returns (these weights are coming from outside of the portfolio and summation of these weights are 1 for each day), so for days 1 and 2, the returns are $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ and later for calculating the average return of this portfolio for 300 days we calculate the average of these returns ($R_{1}$, $R_{2}$, ..).

1. Is this procedure correct?
2. Now, suppose that we want to have log returns. There are two ways to reach log returns. First, calculate the log return of each trade $(ln(Pt/Pt−1)$ and continue the mentioned steps. The other one is when we reach the daily returns, we use $Rn=ln(1+R)$ for calculating daily log returns, and the average is the log return of the portfolio (daily).

Comment: Yes. you are correct. But what will you be doing or saying about the result?

Comment: @RalphWinters I have different portfolios with different weights to compare them later. What about part 2? Do you have any idea about the correct way of calculating this portfolio's log(return)?

Comment: Your example shows you made 5 trades on one day so that is your return for the day. What is the purpose of the weighting after the trades?

Comment: @RalphWinters This is a zero net-investment strategy. I'm just showing one leg here.

Answer (score 3):

*Now this is a farily basic question, but since I see professionals having trouble with this all the time, let us go through it*

Simple returns aggregate nicely (linearly) across trades but not time, whereas log-returns aggregate nicely across time but not trades. So when you take arithmetic average of simple returns across time, you make a minor travesty...

### 1. The "return" of the returns, simple vs log

If $S$ denotesthe asset value, then the
simple return between day $d-1$ and day $d$ is $R_d := S_d/S_{d-1} - 1$, and log-return $r_d := \ln(S_d/S_{d-1})$, such that the relation $r_d=\ln(1+R_d) \iff R_d=\exp(r_d)-1$ holds.

#### 1.1. Why log-returns are Normal, and simple returns are "abnormal"...

If the asset price $S$ is Log-normally distributed (e.g. stocks), then log-returns are Normally distributed and additive. That is, if $S_d=S_{d-1}\exp(\nu \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z_d)$, then

\begin{align}
R_d&=\exp(\nu \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z_d)-1, \\
r_d&=\nu \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z_d.
\end{align}

That is, log-returns are nicely Normally distributed, whereas simple returns are shifted Log-normally distributed, and less nice...

#### 1.2. Averaging log-returns makes sense across time, simple returns do not

The arithmetic mean of the daily log-returns is an unbiased estimator of the drift term
$\hat{\nu}\Delta t:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d=1}^n r_d$, whereas for the simple returns, we would have to do a geometric mean, which will be a biased estimate of the drift term. Arithmetic mean of the simple returns does not have the same practical meaning in this case.

### 2. Relationship therapy between simple and log returns

To simplify notation let $X_{day}^{(trade)}:=X_{day,trade}$, and let $X_{day}$ be aggregated over trades, and $X^{(trade)}$ be a trade aggregated over time. Aggregation over trades and time is $X$.

#### 2.1. Fixed time, across trades

\begin{align}
R_d &= \sum_{i=1}^m w_i R_d^{(i)}, \\
r_d :&= \ln(1 + R_d) = \ln(1 + \sum_{i=1}^m w_i R_d^{(i)}) = \ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^m w_i \exp(r_d^{(i)})\right),
\end{align}
where we can see that simple returns linearly aggregate across trades, whereas log-returns do **not**.

#### 2.2. Fixed trade, across time

\begin{align}
R^{(i)} &= \prod_{d=1}^n (1+R_d^{(i)})-1, \\
r^{(i)} &:= \ln(1 + R^{(i)}) = \sum_{d=1}^n \ln(1+R_d^{(i)}) = \sum_{d=1}^n r_d^{(i)},
\end{align}
where we can see that simple returns do **not** linearly aggregates across trades, whereas log-returns do.

#### 2.3. Across trades and across time

Now in order to get the total return for the portfolio, you have two options

1. **Aggregate across trades, then time**

   1. Aggregate across trades in simple returns $R_d=\sum_{i=1}^m w_i R_d^{(i)}$ for all $d$ays.
   2. Convert to log-returns $r_d := \ln(1+R_d)$.
   3. Aggregate (sum) across time $r=\sum_{d=1}^n r_d$.
   4. Optionally convert back to simple return via $R=\exp(r)-1$.
2. **Aggregate across time, then trades**

   1. Aggregate across time in log-returns $r^{(i)}=\sum_{d=1}^n r_d^{(i)}$.
   2. Convert to simple returns $R^{(i)} := \exp(r^{(i)})-1$.
   3. Aggregate across trades in simple returns $R=\sum_{i=1}^m w_iR^{(i)}$.
   4. Optionally convert back to log-returns via $r=\ln(1+R)$.

Now it is unfortunately common to see people that purely work with log-returns by linearly aggregating across trades and time. Implicitly they are assuming that $r_d^{(i)} \approx R_d^{(i)}$, which is true for small returns. However, when this is not the case, or when summing many small returns e.g. return over large horizons, this might cause large errors.

Comment: Great answer (+1). Quick point on 1.1: Simple returns, $R_d=\frac{S_d}{S_{d-1}}-1$, are *not* log-normally distributed. _Gross returns_, $\frac{S_d}{S_{d-1}}$ are log-normally distributed. Once you subtract a constant, it's no longer log-normal (think of the [support of the distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299482/is-cy-lognormal)). Of course, all of the analysis depends on prices being log-normally distributed to start with.

Comment: @Kevin: nice catch! Edited to shifted log-normal. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score -2):

Heyya
Hawaii, Get into returns world. Do some proper calculations than just sending a formula. Use a real time example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).